# selecting values from different columns, checking for nan and forming new column based on conditions

Tags: pandas

I have a df

| .. | Doc2 | DayType |
| --- | --- | --- |
| .. | NaN | 0 |
| .. | PQ | Holiday |
| .. | NaN | Holiday |
| .. | PJ | 0 |

I have to form a new column 'AssistanceFactor' such that its value is
1 if Doc2 is NaN and DayType is 'Holiday'

1 if Doc2 is not Nan and DayType is 'Holiday'

0.75 if Doc2 is not Nan and DayType is not 'Holiday'

1 if Doc2 is not NaN and DayType is not 'Holiday'

What would be the best method for this?
I tried iterrows and conditions as well as np.select /where. But I am not getting the hang of it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: So basically you want 0.75 if Doc2 is not NaN and DayType not Holiday and 1 otherwise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because 3 conditions return `1` and one return `0.75` is possible test only `3rd` condition:

```
df['AssistanceFactor'] = np.where(df.Doc2.notna() & df.DayType.ne('Holiday'), 0.75, 1)
```

Comment: So, do you consider it a duplicate or not? ;)

Comment: @mozway - for 90%, there is not test `notna` ;)

Comment: I tried this, but I get an error saying length of values not matching length of index. Any solutions?

Comment: @dratoms - there is compared `df` and assign to `df` ? all same Dataframe?